# Prove that a set $E$ is closed iff it's complement $E^{c}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

I was wondering if this proof was right.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose $E$ is closed. Then choose $x\in E^{c}$, then $x\notin E$, and so $x$ is not a limit point of $E$.

Hence there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $E \cap N$ is empty, such that $N \subset E^{c}$. Thus $x$ is an interior point of $E^{c}$ and $E^{c}$ is open

$\Rightarrow$ Then suppose $E^{c}$ is open. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$, so that $x$ is not an interior point of $E^{c}$. Since $E^{c}$ is open, this means that $ x \in E$, Therefore $E$ is closed.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: looks fine!!!!! Amen~

Comment: You should make explicit what definition of open and closed you are using. For example, last week I defined to my students that a set is closed if its complemente is open...

Comment: @Suarez-Alvarez, Isn't that what the OP is saying (that the set is closed if its compliment is open)? I am only asking as I am confused how this example is supposed to differ from the OP's.

Comment: You are reading Rudin aren't you (at least you were, since this post is old). You could have taken E = E^c in the theorem above to prove this corollary and notice thzt E  = (E^c)^c.

Comment: I don't think this proof is correct. Even if $x\notin E$, it could still be a limit point of $E$; limit points do not have to be contained in the set.

Comment: Consider if $E$ and $E^c$ open (for instance the interval $(0,1)$ and its complement). If both are open, there are limit points not contained in either of them. This contradicts the definition of complement!

Answer (score 7):

Looks good. All true statements and they make logical sense. However, it kinda depends on where you start. Is this meant to be a proof for metric spaces? Then it's absolutely fine. Or is it a proof for topological spaces? For topological spaces, the definition of being a closed set is usually that the complement is open. You could use the same definition for metric spaces, but that's usually not done. So it depends on the definitions from which you start.

Comment: I also thought that this is the definition of closed...

Comment: @vanguard2k there are many definitions. One could define a set $A\subset X$ to be closed when every element $x$ of $X$ with the property that Intersection of every neighbourhood of $x$ with $A$ is not empty already is in $A$.

Comment: @Ralph in fact we used that definition in analysis 1 which might be your calculus

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis Of course. Like you and Mariano Suarez-Alvarez said the definition is important. So user77107 simply proved a different characterization of closed.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah your proof looks fine, but you should give us the definition of closed and open. Because it is not unusual to define a set is closed when its complement is open. You should maybe defend what happens when $E=\varnothing$ or $E^C = \varnothing$.