# Is the complement of a closed set always open?

Tags: general-topology

My book says that that a set is closed if its complement is open. Can a set be closed for other reason or is this if supposed to be an iff? Is there a way to prove this statement?

Comment: Usually, that's how closed sets are defined. Regardless, $A$ is open iff $A^C$ is closed.

Comment: It depends on which books you are reading. If it is a book on topology, very likely it is a definition. If it is a book on analysis, there might be definitions on both closed and open set and what you stated requires a proof.

Answer (score 13):

This is simply a slightly confusing, but very widespread, convention of mathematical wording.

In statements, “if” is interpreted just as one direction of implication. To specify bidirectional implication, as you say, one needs to write “iff”, or “if and only if”, or “exactly if”, or similar.

In definitions, however, “if” is used for by-definition equivalence, which in particular gives the biconditional. (Quite arguably, it’s exactly the same as a biconditional; logicians can and do split hairs over this issue, but in standard foundations of mathematics, there’s essentially no difference.)

Comment: Astute answer my good sir, +1 upboat to you.

Comment: I would not say there is essentially no difference; after all, this fellow here was confused about it.

Answer (score 10):

By definition, a subset of a topological space is closed if and only if its complement is open.

Comment: Your own definition? My book doesnt have this

Comment: What's the [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392212/prove-that-if-a-set-e-is-closed-iff-its-complement-ec-is-open?rq=1)?

Comment: @terry But your book does have this! At least this is what *you* wrote in your post. I only clarified the definition from your book. Have no doubt, this is the standard definition.

Answer (score 5):

As some of the other answers have said, in the field of *topology*, we *define* a set to be closed if it is the complement of some open set.

The reason this makes sense as a definition is that for all the spaces we study in analysis, the closed sets (i.e., the sets which contain all their limit points) are precisely those sets that are the complements of open sets (i.e., sets theat contain an open ball around every point).

The second statement clearly requires a proof.  I'll let you play around and try and find one for yourself, but yes - there is an 'iff' here - in any metric space $X$, a subset $K\subset X$ is closed *if and only if* $X\setminus K$ is open.  You know how to prove

> $X\setminus K$ is open $\Rightarrow$ $K$ is closed.

Can you also prove

> $K$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ $X\setminus K$ is open?

(You can also find this question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392212/prove-that-if-a-set-e-is-closed-iff-its-complement-ec-is-open?rq=1).)

The point is that when we come to generalize metric spaces to topological spaces, the notion of a set 'containing all its limit points' is no longer a good one, so we instead *define* a set to be closed if and only if it is the complement of an open set.  But we would *never* make that definition if it wasn't true for closed subsets of the metric spaces we study in analysis.