# The complement of open set cannot be open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My instructor said that "The complement of the open set cannot be open" is false and It can be open. I have trouble understanding this  by [Is the complement of a closed set always open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340042/842235).

Can anyone give me an example that a complement of the open set can be open.

Comment: Take any topological space $X$. Then $X$ is open and so is its complement, the empty set. Sets can be both closed and open or they can be neither.

Comment: As an example, with respect to the topological space given by $~\Bbb{R},~$ the two complementary sets $~\Bbb{R}~$ and $~\emptyset~$ are each *both open and closed*.  The topological space given by the complex numbers $~\Bbb{C}~$ is similar.

Comment: The linked question is irrelevant for the purpose of what you are asking.

Comment: The rudimentary concepts that I was taught, which pertain to the Complex Numbers $~\Bbb{C}~$ is that [1] A set is open if and only if each of its elements is an interior point.  [2] A set is closed if and only if its complement (with respect to the topological space) is open.

Comment: In any set $X$ equipped with the discrete topology, *every* set is open, and in particular the complement of *any* open set is open.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you

Comment: in addition to the extreme cases of all space and the empty set in discrete topology every set is open and closed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space).

Answer (score 0):

The open sets of a set are just, loosely speaking, collections of subsets which have nice closure properties under intersection and union. So it shouldn't be surprising that their complements could coincide with other open sets, as long as those "closure properties" are satisfied; in other words, there is no reason why they shouldn't coincide. For example, consider $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and the topology $\tau=\{\{a\}, \{b,c\}, X, \emptyset\}$. This topology has as closed sets the collection $\phi=\{X,\emptyset,\{b,c\}, \{a\}\}=\tau$. So in this topology every open set is also closed.

This question arises because one often has a myopic view of topology, seeing as the likely introduction to these concepts was done through studying the euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an extraordinarily amicable topological space; every nice property you can think of, euclidean spaces have it. One of those nice properties is **connectability**: the property that the only subsets which are both closed and open, are the entire space and the empty set.  So it's no wonder that we conceptualize open and closed sets as being somehow opposite; this is true, in connected spaces! But as we strip the space of structure and dive into more general topologies, we quickly find that this is not always the case.